# Free Genealogy Software

Tags: gratis, genealogy

I'm looking for a free program that I can use to create and document fictional family trees. It needs to either be desktop or able to run on Chrome OS. I'd prefer if I was able to give a person multiple partners, more than two parents, and add information about the family members, but these are not necessary.

Comment: Has a web search on "genealogy software free" been any help? When I ran that search, it certainly gave me a lot of promising results. The program I hear about most often is Family Tree Builder.

Comment: If you specifically want it to run on ChromeOS, add that to the search terms.

Comment: i have already tried that. i would also like to mention that Family Tree Builder is a download program that does not run on Chrome OS, which does not work for me at all.

Answer (score 3):

I personally have found [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/introduction-WP/) very good!

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Lots of very good charts
- You can embed or link to documents & images
- Multiple Views
- Add significant events
- Eight output formats are supported by Gramps: PDF, OpenDocument, HTML, Rich Text Format (RTF), Latex, and plain text.
- Builtin and Custom reports
- Multiple formats are supported by Gramps for charts and graphs: OpenDocument Draw, PDF, PostScript, and SVG.
- GEDCOM import and export.
- Active community involvement
- Multi-platform including Linux, Windows and Mac
- It seems to also be available for Chromebook, (See [here](https://www.bestchromebookapps.com/gramps-for-chromebook/)).
- There is an [Online Demo](https://www.rollapp.com/app/gramps).
- No problems with adding multiple partners, parents or other relationships.

Comment: Y'know what's funny? Even though I figured it was probably programmed in Python, I wasn't *absolutely sure* until I went to their site to confirm.

Comment: @JohnY - I deliberately didn't mention that it was written in python as it is done in a way that is transparent to the end user, i.e. you don't have to know python or even that it is written in python to install and use it. :-)

Comment: I wasn't expecting the software's implementation language to "show through". I actually use plenty of software that I had no idea was written in Python when I started using it, and would *still* have no idea was written in Python if I weren't the kind of person to dig into that stuff. But this was a recommendation from *Steve Barnes* so the odds of it not being Python were pretty small, just from a purely statistical perspective. ;)

Comment: @JohnY - You know me so well :-) - The one that I was surprised was python was MicroSoft Box Sync!